# SystemTray for jdk 1.5

Tags: java, system-tray, java-6, java-5

I am converting code from jdk 1.6 to jdk 1.5 and the code is:

```
import java.awt.SystemTray;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    }

    try {
       tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
       System.err.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
}
```

Could you guys tell me what will be the compatible code for this?

Comment: I doubt your code will compile, but I suppose that's not the point...

Comment: the code would not compile...coz you had putted reference variable `SystemTray tray` in the if condition and in `try{}` block you had tried to use the instance of `SystemTray` via `tray` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can try any one of them

[JDIC (JDesktop Integration Components)](https://jdic.dev.java.net/)

[JTray](http://www.jpackages.com/jtray/)

Answer (score 1):

You need external (probably JNI) libraries to support that in Java 5. [Here](http://jeans.studentenweb.org/java/trayicon/trayicon.html) is an example for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`java.awt.SystemTray` is not a part of JDK 5 so you will need some external libraries, e.g. [Systray](http://systray.sourceforge.net/).